# Cpu photolithography by order

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I made a couple of processor architectures based on risk-v,  And I would like to know if there are companies that make cpu by order,I don’t want to make homemade processors based on PSB boards because it’s stupid :(

Unfortunately, I am not a millionaire to order from tsmc factories, and I would like to place an order around for 10k€, does such a company exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a 130nm process is good enough for you, you can even get your design produced free of charge. And costs are not too high if you won't get into the Google shuttle for free - see https://efabless.com/ - you can easily fit in under 10k in total costs. The OpenLane flow is 100% open source and is very easy to use.

Of course, you'd better verify your design in simulation and on an FPGA first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you know other companies that make CPUs? I need it for x86 architecture

Comment: @ianclover You must be really careful if you want to produce an x86 clone. Better avoid doing it, or stick to FPGA implementations, otherwise legal consequences can be very unpleasant.

Comment: ahh... Okay fine, thx for reply